# Sharing class data to component in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I am creating a login system in angular 5. For same, I have created a class file with name **user.ts**

User.ts:

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public  id: number,
    public  username: string,
    public  password: string,
    public  firstName: string,
    public  lastName: string) { }
  }

var users = [
    new User(1, 'user1', 'user1', 'John', 'Cena'),
    new User(2, 'user2', 'user2', 'Randy', 'Orton'),
    new User(3, 'user3', 'user3', 'Jeff', 'Hardy'),
    new User(4, 'user4', 'user4', 'Matt', 'Hardy'),
    new User(5, 'user5', 'user5', 'AJ', 'Styles')
];
```

Also, I have created a login component, which has code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from "../user";

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   usernameTxt: string;
   passwordTxt: string;

   login() {
    //login code
   }
}
```

As I am new to angular 5, I wanted to check the user input from the front end with the array mention in user.ts

How can I check the credentials are same as in User class

Comment: how you are checking the credentials?

Comment: there will be front-end login form which will be passing the value...

Comment: so you should be comparing the username & password from the existing array?

Comment: I have updated the code, yes need to compare with the array in user.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below code to make it work instead of using forEach

```
var authenticatedUser = data.find(u => u.username === this.usernameTxt);

if(authenticatedUser && authenticatedUser.password === this.passwordTxt){

  this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);

}else{
  alert("Invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared service to connect and validate the `username` and `password`

```
@Injectable()
    export class SharedService{ 
      users = [
                  new User(1, 'user1', 'user1', 'John', 'Cena'),
                  new User(2, 'user2', 'user2', 'Randy', 'Orton'),
                  new User(3, 'user3', 'user3', 'Jeff', 'Hardy'),
                  new User(4, 'user4', 'user4', 'Matt', 'Hardy'),
                  new User(5, 'user5', 'user5', 'AJ', 'Styles')
            ];
    }
```

In your login component you can validate it by injecting the `constructor`

```
constructor(private sharedService:SharedService){}
login(){
  this.sharedService.forEach(item => {
      if(item.userName === this.username && item.password === this.password) {
       // do something;
  });
}
```

Comment: that SharedService will be in user.ts

Comment: You can have it anywhere and import and have it in providers of module